# WPF VB.net Close Page

Tags: wpf, vb.net

A event in MainWIndow.xaml.vb opens Page1.xaml. I have a button on Page1. How can I close Page1 by click the button on Page1 to close just Page1.xaml and NOT the main Window (MainWindow.xaml)???

Comment: How are you calling the page? Pages are intended to be hosted within another container, such as a window.

Answer (score 2):

In the Button_Click Event in Page1 You just write:

```
Me.Close()
```

This will Close only Page1